# Regex for nginx server_name

Tags: nginx

I would like to use a regex on my nginx `server_name` that functions almost like a wildcard.

*-dev.mydomain.com -> dev server (localhost port 3001)
*-staging.mydomain.com -> staging server (localhost port 3002)
everything else -> prod server (localhost port 3000)

However I cannot for the life of me get this to work.

I seemingly get it working on https://regexr.com/51teh - but I'm not able to apply it correctly to my nginx config.

Here is my staging config now (not working, not catching requests to `*-staging.mydomain.com`):

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name "~.*-staging\.mydomain\.com";
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

Comment: [Read this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) and you see that *regular expressions* come right at the bottom of the list. You will need to remove all wild card `server_name` directives from your other `server` blocks and change them to *regular expression* server blocks too. Order the *regular expressions* with the more specific match first.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you, this is what I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another virtual server block with `default_server` to the listen directive. Something like the following:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl default_server;
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
}

  server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name "~.*-staging\.mydomain\.com";
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

This should work.